# Create a new remote project with JetBrains Gateway

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-gateway

I have a preexisting Python project on github and want to use PyCharm 2022.3.1 to work remotely via SSH on that project. For this reason, I use JetBrains Gateway to connect to the remote. The SSH connection seems to work properly.
However, PyCharm is not willing to set up a new project for my cloned repository, after I passed the path in the following dialogue.

[image]

The final window that will open after specifying the path looks like this.

[image]

As you can see, there are no files available in the explorer and nothing is being loaded, even though files exist in this directory.
It must be noted that I don't have a `.idea` directory for the project yet, but would expect PyCharm to set one up for me.
Unfortunately I can't find a way to do so.
I don't want to create a `.idea` directory locally and add it to the repository because I don't want the repository to contain IDE specific files.
Interestingly, I have another project on the remote, which I was able to setup with a previous version of PyCharm / Gateway.

So is there any way for me to create a new PyCharm project on the remote with Gateway?